# Tuple mapping in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, tuples

I don't know how it's usually called, but what I need is something like this:

```
f a b c = a + 2 * b + 3 * c

map f [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```

i.e. mapping list of n-tuples to a function with n separate arguments. Is there a built-in way to do this in Haskell?

P.S.: I've found `uncurry` just now, but it doesn't seem to work this way with 3 arguments, only with 2.

Comment: Any reason your f doesn't take a single 3-tuple-argument? Otherwise you can make your own function to do the "conversion" in the call: `threeArgApply f (x,y,z) = f x y z`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your own function:

```
uncurry3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (a,b,c) -> d
uncurry3 f (a,b,c) = f a b c

map (uncurry3 f) [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```

Alternatively, you can use `uncurryN` from the `tuple` package which works for tuple sizes up to 15:

```
cabal install tuple

import Data.Tuple.Curry

map (uncurryN f) [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```

Comment: Thanks, used the `uncurryN` function. And why isn't it in the standard library?..

Comment: I'm glad to help. I think it's not in the standard libraries because it is not needed that often and it uses some GHC extensions.

Answer (score 2):

in general, no - because tuples are not so generic as lists, and may have different data types

however you may rework your tuples in the way of ((a,b), c) and then you may want to use either fst/snd combinations or [Arrows](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/) to generalize your computations.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Imagine a function `f :: a -> b -> c -> d`, then it is perfectly fine to "apply" it to a tuple of type `(a,b,c)`. (And anyway, there's no fundamental difference between `((a,b),c)` and `(a,b,c)`, except the first allows you to use `uncurry (uncurry f)` instead of having to do one of the solutions others have proposed.)

Comment: Yes, I know, I just tried to show different way of solving the task, which may lead to nice and concise code, especially using Awrrows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any general solution to this problem, but the practical solution would be

```
uncurry3 f (x, y, z)  =  f x y z
```

Then

```
map (uncurry3 f) [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```